# SQL Server table collation with greek

Tags: sql-server, collation

I have two tables in SQL Server with collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

**TableA**

```
columnA1    varchar(100),
columnA2    varchar(100)
```

**TableB**

```
columnB1    varchar(100)
```

I insert a row in `TableA`, filling the columns with

```
columnA1 -> a value coming from a form of a 'UTF-8' page
columnA2 -> the value of columnB1 from TableB
```

Both values are in greek.

The problem is that when i select the new inserted row, `columnA1` displays the value correct (with greek letters), but `columnA2` displays `???` instead of greek letters.

When i select `columnB1` from `TableB` displays the value with greek letters

Comment: Which query do you use to insert the new row?

Comment: I think using Nvarchar Or Nchar Type for storing and retrieving Greek characters works fine.

Comment: i cannot change data type to nvarchar.

Comment: INSER INTO TableA(columnA1, columnA2) VALUES ('Καλημέρα', 'Καλησπέρα')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. The mistake was in the collation of the columns. Both tables have a `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation, So does `columnA2` and `columnB1`, but `columA1` has a `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI` collation, so that's why it display Greek correctly

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to prefix a Unicode character string constant with the letter **N** to signal UCS-2 or UTF-16 input.

```
INSERT INTO Table (Col) VALUES (N'Ελληνικά')
```

[MSDN citation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)